# Excluding a level in your categorical variable to fit your hypothesis

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I have a categorical variable with 3 levels: Attention Deficit, Other Types of Deficit, No Deficit. My hypothesis is only interested in comparing Attention Deficit and Other Types Deficit using regression. Is it right to exclude the subjects with no deficit from my sample when I run the regression? Meaning I will have only one dummy coded variable in my regression?

Comment: What are you trying to compare between the two samples correspond to "Attention Deficit" and "Other Types Deficit" levels of your categorical variable?

Comment: @Epaminondas  binary outcome: Pass or fail. I am using logistic regression.

Comment: You do not need to exclude "No Deficit" from your sample, since including this level will allow you in addition to compare the three levels of your variable.

Comment: @Epaminondas That is only true if you exclude the constant.

Comment: @Epaminondas I understand that I can still make comparisons between Attention Deficit and Other Types Deficit if I keep No Deficit in my sample/categorical variable, regardless of which level I used as my reference group. But I would to know if it theoretically right for me exclude No Deficit cases from my sample simply because it is not of interest/part of my hypothesis, hence I would only have 2 levels in the categorical variable.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, eliminating conditions from your analysis is frowned upon. Statistically, anything is possible, but from a research perspective, it might not be.

You can contrast only the two conditions you are interested in, but include the complete analysis/data in your reporting. Here's a great paper which talks about that and other related issues in psych research https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0956797611417632

Comment: Dropping a condition is done to allow the dropped condition to be contained in the intercept term, but those data points are still considered in the regression.

Comment: @Dave " Is it right to exclude the subjects with no deficit from my sample when I run the regression? " This definitely suggests they were looking at excluding the subjects entirely from the analysis. I wouldn't term what you are saying as "dropping a condition" but "collapsing across conditions". That way they would be included in the regression but wont get their own estimates.

Comment: I do not follow. Could you please clarify?

Comment: The OP suggested they wanted to exclude the subjects from the regression. I don't think that's kosher at all. One could say "conditions A and B were similar / not our focal interest in this work so we consider all subjects in conditions A and B as similar" - thereby collapsing across conditions A and B. But entirely dropping condition B from the analysis would be an unethical research practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare Attention Deficit with Other Deficit then it is convenient to exclude Other Deficit from your model. That way the parameter for Attention Deficit will be directly the comparison of Attention Deficit with Other Deficit.

In the comments you mention that you will use this in logistic regression, so lets use an example with logistic regression. Say we want to explain union membership if women in the USA with marital status, race and education (`grade_c`, which is centered at 12 years of education($\approx$highschool)). In particular we are interested in the comparison never married versus married. The exponentiated constant is the odds of union membership for those women who are married, white, and finished highschool, that is, have the value 0 on all explanatory variables. So for married white highschool graduates we expect to find .24 union-members for every non-union-member. The other coefficients are odds ratios, which are ratios of odds. So if one is never married than the odds will increase by a (nonsignificant) factor $1.27$, or an increase of $(1.27 - 1)\times 100\%= 27\%$. So by excluding the married dummy, the coefficient for never married is directly a comparison between the married and never married.

```
. logit union ib2.marst i.race grade_c, or base nolog

Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =      1,876
                                                LR chi2(5)        =      35.73
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -1027.0716                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0171

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            union | Odds Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
            marst |
   never married  |   1.274812   .2173981     1.42   0.155     .9126157    1.780757
widowed/divorced  |   1.145731   .1489955     1.05   0.295     .8879514    1.478347
         married  |          1  (base)
                  |
             race |
           white  |          1  (base)
           black  |   1.567148   .1929431     3.65   0.000     1.231154    1.994839
           other  |   1.760592   .7811568     1.27   0.202     .7378863    4.200763
                  |
          grade_c |   1.100223   .0237531     4.42   0.000     1.054638    1.147777
            _cons |   .2352931   .0195246   -17.44   0.000     .1999754    .2768482
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

@Epaminondas mentioned that you do not have to exclude any dummy. This is true if you exclude the constant, but will dramatically change the interpretation of your coefficients. Now the exponentiated coeffcients of the marital status dummies are no longer odds ratios, but odds. So to continue the example: For married white highschool graduates the odds of being a union member is 0.30, while for never married white highschool graduates the odds of being a union member is 0.27. We can compare those odds by computing their ratio, and if we do so we get the odds ratio of 1.27 we got in the first example. So both are just different representations of the same model. Both can be useful, but if you want to focus on the comparison, then the first is a more direct way of doing so.

```
. logit union ibn.marst i.race grade_c, or base nolog nocons

Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =      1,876
                                                Wald chi2(6)      =     447.72
Log likelihood = -1027.0716                     Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            union | Odds Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
            marst |
   never married  |   .2999546   .0513313    -7.04   0.000     .2144812    .4194901
widowed/divorced  |   .2695827    .033444   -10.57   0.000     .2113943    .3437881
         married  |   .2352931   .0195246   -17.44   0.000     .1999755    .2768482
                  |
             race |
           white  |          1  (base)
           black  |   1.567148   .1929431     3.65   0.000     1.231154    1.994839
           other  |   1.760592   .7811567     1.27   0.202     .7378862    4.200763
                  |
          grade_c |   1.100223   .0237531     4.42   0.000     1.054638    1.147777
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. di .2999546 / .2352931
1.2748126
```

Comment: @Marteen Buis I see that you have all three levels in both of your outputs. And the number of observation is also the same, meaning you did not remove any observation. My question was if, in this context, I want to compare only married vs never married. Is it statistically right to remove those who are widowed/divorced? Correct me if I am wrong, but the explanation you gave depends on the contrast bonding that you use for your dummy variables? So for the first model you used set last to zero?

Comment: In the first model the married category was excluded, which is equivalent to setting the log odds ratio to zero and this the odds ratio to one.

Comment: So observations that were widowed/divorced are not removed from the sample but simply set as the reference group.

Comment: No, the married are exluded from the model, so they are the reference group. Both never married and divorced are compared with the married.